# how to avoid polygon being clipped with tileset?

Tags: mapbox, mbtiles, tippecanoe

I am generating a layer UK scale, it is composed for several polygons, the idea for the layer is to display it fully and then the user can zoom to most specific area. The main problem is because the number of polygons when I create the .mbtile it split some of the polygon at determined zooms.

I have tried with different options of [tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe) like --not duplication extend zooms if still dropping ... but I couldn't nail whit the correct commands to make it work.
[image: polygons splited at some zoom]

```
tippecanoe -zg --read-parallel -l $LAYER -o "$OUT_MBTILES" "$OUT_JSON" --coalesce-densest-as-needed --extend-zooms-if-still-dropping --no-duplication
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is somehow related to `--no-duplication`. Per the documentation:

> `--no-duplication`: As with `--no-clipping`, each feature is included intact instead of cut to tile boundaries. In addition, it is included only in a single tile per zoom level rather than potentially in multiple copies. Clients of the tileset must check adjacent tiles (possibly some distance away) to ensure they have all features.

I'm not sure why you're using that option, but disable it if possible.

It's hard to be more specific without seeing your data and having a lot more information about what you're trying to achieve, zoom levels, attributes, data size etc.